# java how to make integer value auto-increment in textfile?

Tags: java, text-files

So far my code until here.

```
String name;
int age;
int max = 0;
Scanner y = null;
try 
{
    y = new Scanner(new File("new_member.txt"));
    while(y.hasNext())
    {
        int a = y.nextInt();
        max = a;
        String name=txtname.getText();
        int age=Integer.parseInt(txtage.getText());
    }
    y.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Formatter x = null;
try 
{
    FileWriter f = new FileWriter("new_member.txt", true);
    x = new Formatter(f);
    x.format("%d %s %d%n",++max,name,age);
    x.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i am trying to make my text file result like this.
anyone can help?

```
1 Ahmed  15
2 Hamada 16
3 Johny 12
4 Terry 14
5 Jack 13
6 Sarah 12
```

After that next data save in to text file should be
7 and so on

Comment: Make sure to provide compilable code. This snippet has many errors.

Comment: In short, you need to use Collections (such as ArrayList) and a `for` loop. I would start by researching those two topics.